# Display a simple counter of currently logged in users using php, pdo and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I have been searching for days for such a very simple counter that displays a number of currently logged in users on my website - however, have had no luck finding anything.  And the stuff I have found all relates to the deprecated *mysql_functions.... :( - sigh...

All I am looking for is how to make this work as I literally cannot figure this out - one would think it is very easy but holy crap, after searching and searching, it seems like there are just so many different ways to accomplish this and sadly everything I have found is what I mentioned above (stuff using the deprecated mysql_functions)...

Anyway, this is all that I am looking to do:

1.) Adding `lastactivity` or `lastseen` in my `users` table either based on a timestamp or perhaps a tinyint(1) with default 0 which equals user logged out of which would switch to 1 if user is logged in...

2.) Creating a class for this using php version (5.4.24) with PDO driver based on what is in my database table `users` which would update and select what is in my database table `users` every 5-10 minutes which would output the number of currently logged in users.

3.) Being able to use `<?php echo $lastactivity; ?>` or `<?php echo $lastseen; ?>` to display the number of users currently logged in on each page I place this piece of code on...

4.) All of which trying to stay away from basing this on SESSIONS if possible...

If anyone could shed some light on how to accomplish this, I would be very grateful!

**UPDATE:**

what would be in my `users` table:

```
lastseen | tinyint(1) | Default 0
lastactivity | timestamp | Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

what I currently have in my `users.php` class page - I'll display everything I have atm so be prepared for a lot - nothing pertaining to a counter of logged in users is in this yet, however, with what I do have I hope will shed some light on how to add what I need to it...:

```
class Users {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;
    }

    public function update_user($clan_tag,
                    $gamer_tag,
                    $gender,
                    $day,
                    $month,
                    $year,
                    $location,
                    $occupation,
                    $interests,
                    $bio,
                    $status,
                    $xfire,
                    $steam,
                    $image_location,
                    $id) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET
                                `clan_tag`      = ?,
                                `gamer_tag`     = ?,
                                `gender`        = ?,
                                `day`           = ?,
                                `month`         = ?,
                                `year`          = ?,
                                `location`      = ?,
                                `occupation`        = ?,
                                `interests`     = ?,
                                `bio`           = ?,
                                `status`        = ?,
                                `xfire`         = ?,
                                `steam`         = ?,
                                `image_location`    = ?

                                WHERE `id`      = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $clan_tag);
        $query->bindValue(2, $gamer_tag);
        $query->bindValue(3, $gender);
        $query->bindValue(4, $day);
        $query->bindValue(5, $month);
        $query->bindValue(6, $year);
        $query->bindValue(7, $location);
        $query->bindValue(8, $occupation);
        $query->bindValue(9, $interests);
        $query->bindValue(10, $bio);
        $query->bindValue(11, $status);
        $query->bindValue(12, $xfire);
        $query->bindValue(13, $steam);
        $query->bindValue(14, $image_location);
        $query->bindValue(15, $id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    // update_status below has been duplicated from what is above to suit needs. Without this update, status update does not work in logster.php!
    public function update_status($status, $id){

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET
                                `status`        = ?
                                WHERE `id`      = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $status);
        $query->bindValue(2, $id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function change_password($user_id, $password) {

        global $bcrypt;

        $password_hash = $bcrypt->genHash($password);

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $password_hash);
        $query->bindValue(2, $user_id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
            return true;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


        public function fetch_info($what, $field, $value){
        /* (Add more here if new columns/rows are added to table) */
        $allowed = array('id',
                 'username',
                 'clan_tag',
                 'gamer_tag',
                 'gender',
                 'day',
                 'month',
                 'year',
                 'location',
                 'occupation',
                 'interests',
                 'bio',
                 'status',
                 'xfire',
                 'steam',
                 'email');

        if (!in_array($what, $allowed, true) || !in_array($field, $allowed, true)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }else{

            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT $what FROM `users` WHERE $field = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $value);

            try{

                $query->execute();

            } catch(PDOException $e){

                die($e->getMessage());
            }

            return $query->fetchColumn();
        }
    }


    public function user_exists($username) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {

        global $bcrypt;

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `password`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $data               = $query->fetch();
            $stored_password        = $data['password'];
            $id                 = $data['id'];

            if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){
                return $id;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function userdata($id) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);

        try{

            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e){

            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function get_users() {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `time` DESC");

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

What would be included on each page to display number of currently logged in users:

either `<?php echo $lastseen; ?>` or `<?php echo $lastactivity; ?>`

**UPDATE 2:**

Including my logout function:

```
class General{
        // Note: Created to specify what logged in users can see/view and edit/update
    public function logged_in () {
        return(isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
    }
        // Note: Created to specify what a specific individual or user can see/view and edit/update
    public function logged_in_protect() {
        if ($this->logged_in() === true) {
                header('Location: home.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
        // Note: Created to specify what non-users - (those who are not logged in and/or do not have an account) can see/view only - (edit/update is unavailable)
    public function logged_out_protect() {
        if ($this->logged_in() === false) {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
```

Comment: You don't need sessions to do this. You can base yourself on the following: 
`mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE table_name SET counter=counter+$value WHERE column='the_column'");` - `$value` being a variable you want to set as.

Comment: how would I accomplish this if I'm not using `mysqli` and instead using prepared statements with pdo/mysql?

Comment: A query is a query. You can just omit the `mysqli` part and use the standard SQL syntax. I.e.: `"UPDATE table_name SET counter=counter+$value WHERE column='the_column'"` and use your own API.

Comment: I apologize if I sound extremely noobish, but I am when it comes to php.  Based on that syntax, if i created a total of two columns in my `users` table titled: lastseen that has a timestamp with default being current_timestamp and another being lastactivity that has tinyint(1) with default as 0, how would I go about creating the php side of things to make a counter of currently logged in users based on what I have in my table?  I'm literally lost...and everything that I have read doesn't pertain prepared statements or pdo...

Comment: *Thinking.......* (give me a minute or so) ;-)

Comment: ok.  You also mention something about using my own API, how would I create one to suit this.  And thank you for helping out, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: In regular `mysqli_*` it would be done this way to echo the row in question for the counter: 
`while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['counter_column_name'];}` used in conjunction with a `WHERE column='$id'` clause. For the API, I meant your PDO DB/connection.

Comment: Bare with me on this, I'll update my post of what I have thus far in my users.php class page.  One minute...

Comment: I just saw your code now. And to tell you the truth, it would take me a while to figure out just where to put that. I'm no PRO when it comes to classes and multiple functions :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of "lastseen", let's call the column "loggedIn".  That way, a boolean 0 or 1 makes sense. Expand your existing login function to change loggedIn from 0 to 1:

   ```
   if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){
           return $id;
   //update database
   $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `loggedIn` = `1` 
                                WHERE `username` = ?");
   $query->bindValue(1, $username);
   $query->execute();

       }else{
           return false;
       }
   ```

Obviously you'll need a similar statement in the logout function to set the value back to 0.

2 & 3. You could then add this as an additional function of the Users class:

```
public function usersLoggedIn() {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS loggedInCount FROM users 
                                 WHERE loggedIn = 1");
    try {
        $query->execute();

        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {   
            $loggedIn = $row['loggedInCount'];
        }
        return $loggedIn;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still confused on how this would work...would the table be automatically updated once a user logs in and out displaying the correct number of logged in users without a time interval?  Also, I'll again update my post to include my logout function...See original post above in regards to UPDATE 2.

Comment: What I'm seeing there in update 2 is related to the logout function, but not the logout function itself. Typically you're going to see something like:

Comment: What I'm seeing there in update 2 is related to the logout function, but not the logout function itself. Typically you're going to see something like: $_SESSION = array(); which is a quick way to empty the SESSION array. But yes, the table would be automatically updated upon login and logout. If you can find that logout function, that would help. It's important how you're handling sessions as well, since that would provide a potentially simpler way to count who is logged in.

Comment: Okay, I've added an `UPDATE 3` at the bottom of my original post.  That is what I have for my logout...

Comment: Ok, so in your logout function, you would add a snippet to update the database and set the loggedIn field to 0.  //update database
$query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `loggedIn` = `0` 
                             WHERE `username` = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $username);
$query->execute();

Comment: There is one drawback of this approach - if the user just closes the browser without logging out, it will not run this procedure, the database will keep the value of 1, and the count will be slightly incorrect. If you can live with that, then it's fine. Otherwise, you'll have to do this through the use of sessions, which is more involved.

Comment: For the time being, I'm ok with that...So in the logout function I have for my `update 3`, where would that snippet of code be placed?  After the `session_destroy();`?

Comment: and with all that being said, would I even need that `timestamp`?

Comment: Ok, I'm still at a complete loss - it seems to want to work, however, it doesn't update the database at all whether being logged in or out...any ideas?

Comment: First, yes the snippet could go after session_destory(); Second, no you won't need a timestamp unless you want to capture that and do some analysis of when people log in and out. Finally, try the other style of binding values: $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `loggedIn` = `1` 
                             WHERE `username` = :username");
$query->bindValue(:username, $username);                                 If that doesn't work, proceed with normal troubleshooting. You may have an undefined value somewhere. Your function may not have access to a variable (scope problem), etc...